# Select the radio buttons of “Create handouts in Microsoft Word” in Powerpoint 2007 

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2007

How can I write a macro in Powerpoint to select any option (Radio Button) that is displayed when you call "Create Handouts in Microsoft Word" (Office Button-> Publish -> Create Handouts in Microsoft)?

The macro to call "Create Handouts in Microsoft Word" is

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("CreateHandoutsInWord")
```

But I need to know how to write the macro to select the options (like "Notes Next to slide" , "Blank Lines next to line", "Notes below slides" etc...)  from the window that would be displayed when you call the above macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the above question is:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("CreateHandoutsInWord")
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
SendKeys "{DOWN}", True      'Repeat as required...
SendKeys "{ENTER}", False here
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa202943(v=office.10).aspx for more details